# How can I make validate_media_type conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

This is my Document model

Document.rb

```
has_attached_file :document, validate_media_type: false
```

In order to accept documents like '.srt' file, I had to add `validate_media_type: false` to the attachment but I want to make this `validate_media_type` conditional.

So, if it's a .srt file, then validate_media_type will be `false` and for all other files it will be `true`

How can I make `validate_media_type: false` conditional in my Document model?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
  has_attached_file :document, validate_media_type: :content_type_val

def content_type_val
  content_type != 'application/srt'
end
```

please Acknowledge the result.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Didn't work. Added the method, but it's not even getting called. I added a debugger to check whether the `content_type_val ` method is getting executed. It's not.
But adding `false` straight to the attachment works